# Pandas: Query using Levenshtein Distance

Tags: python, string, pandas, levenshtein-distance

Given the following DataSet:

```
name;sex;city;age
john;male;newyork;20
jack;male;newyork;21
mary;female;losangeles;45
maryanne;female;losangeles;48
eric;male;san francisco;26
jenny;female;boston2;30
mattia;na;BostonDynamics;50
```

and the constraints:

```
source = "john"
max_dist = 2
```

my goal is to get a `list` of all name values having a `Levenshtein Distance` with the `source` that is `<= max_dist`. Is it possible to do this by using the `pandas.DataFrame.query()` method or it has to be done in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do it a different way.

```
import editdistance # first do pip install editdistance
from StringIO import StringIO

s = StringIO("""name;sex;city;age
john;male;newyork;20
jack;male;newyork;21
mary;female;losangeles;45
maryanne;female;losangeles;48
eric;male;san francisco;26
jenny;female;boston2;30
mattia;na;BostonDynamics;50""")

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep=';')

df[df.name.apply(lambda x: int(editdistance.eval(source, x)) <= 2)]

   name   sex     city  age
0  john  male  newyork   20


df[df.name.apply(lambda x: int(editdistance.eval(source, x)) <= 2)].name.tolist()

['john']
```

Comment: better is use `df.loc[df.name.apply(lambda x: int(editdistance.eval(source, x)) <= 2), 'name'].tolist()`